# Can not Execute PHP code in Browser

Tags: php, wamp

in the following 2 images i just want to run a very simple php code (file:///C:/wamp/www/test/1.php)

using a running WampServer Version 3.0.6 64bit then the result when i try to execute this file in browser still the same code as i written 
[php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sBWZ.jpg)

[my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ussXd.jpg)

Comment: You should open your file like this ```http://localhost/test/1.php```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are opening a file.In URL its opening file://... but when you want the localhost server to process the file, you need to open your file as `http://localhost/test/1.php`.

Hope it helps. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Put this file into WWW folder of a WAMP-SERVER
then try **localhost/yourFileName.php**

Comment: You should not alter the WWW folder in WAMPServer. Add a subfolder as the OP has done! Or better still create a Virtual Host for each project in any folder anywhere on your disk

Comment: Yes of course, i forget to mention subfolder
**localhost/subFolder/yourFileName.php**